# Is it normal this white substance in my canned green peas?

Tags: food-preservation, canning, spoilage

I just opened a can of petit pois and I found them covered in this white, gooey substance, as opposed (or maybe better "in addition") to the usual clear liquid.

[image: can of peas]

I don't think I have seen it before. I think it's weird that something canned goes bad like that (expiration date is in mid 2020), but I guess it's possible. The weird thing is that I opened a second can (the same brand and kind) and found the same thing. The smell isn't really bad, but I'm still rather hesitant to eat it (in fact I probably won't no matter the answer to this question, but now I'm curious). The cans were stored in a closet cabinet, with the rest of the cans, and I've never had a similar problem before.

I tried to look it up but I didn't find anything clear. Is it possible that this stuff is normal?

Comment: Weird, I haven't seen that before in a can of peas. If both your cans had this it probably means its normal for this particular brand or batch.

Comment: @haakon319 Yes, that's what I thought, that maybe it's normal for this brand... although, I don't know, maybe it could be a bad batch?

Comment: Do these peas have butter or a butter flavored additive?

Comment: @Cindy Thanks for the suggestion, but no, the ingredients list just says "Petit pois, water".

Comment: It just looks like starch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like starch. Several sites I find mention this for different vegetables containing starch, and they all seem to quote [Causes and Possible Solutions for Problems with Canned Foods](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/general/cannedfoodproblems.html) from the National Center for Home Food Preservation (note that these are guidelines for canning):

> Problem:
>       Cloudy liquid (sometimes denotes spoilage)
>
> Causes and solution:
>       1. Starch in vegetables   - Select products at desirable stage of maturity. Do not use overmature vegetables. If canning potatoes, use fresh boiling water to cover and not cooking liquid from preparing hot pack.
>       2. Minerals in water      - Use soft water.
>       3. Additives in salts     - Use pure refined salt (pickling or canning salt) without additives.
>       4. Spoilage               - Prepare food as directed with published canning process. Process by recommended method and for recommended time.

I would just drain and rinse them, and let my taste and smell be the ultimate guide.

[Another guideline formulated a little differently](http://extension.oregonstate.edu/josephine/sites/default/files/sp_50_742_canned_vegetables_problems_and_solutions.pdf)